# GridBagLayout formatting in Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

[image: http://i.imgur.com/oxcEAT5.png]

When I add the second row (of buttons), my textArea disappears.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/P9auZqi.png]

Here is the GridBagLayout code:

```
    public void gridlayout(){

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints grid = new GridBagConstraints();

    grid.gridy = 0;
    grid.gridx = 0;
    add(refreshButton, grid);

    grid.gridx = 1;
    grid.gridwidth = 4;
    add(textArea, grid);

    grid.gridy = 1;
    grid.gridx = 0;
    grid.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    add(button1, grid);

    grid.gridx = 1;
    add(button2, grid);

    grid.gridx = 2;
    add(button3,grid);

    grid.gridx = 3;
    add(button4,grid);

    grid.gridx = 4;
    add(button5,grid);

    grid.gridx = 5;
    add(button6,grid);


}
```

How do I make it so that the refresh button stays on the left and the textArea appears above the second row and takes up the gridx = 1 <----> gridx =5 space?

Comment: You need to set the grid.width for the textArea. It should probably be placed at gridx of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your JTextArea's grid.gridx should be 1, and its grid.gridwidth should likely be 5.
- If you're setting sizes or preferredSizes anywhere don't.
- You should wrap that JTextArea in a JScrollPane and add the scrollpane to the GUI, not the text area.
- If you're not calling `pack()` on the top level window before displaying it, do this.

---

For example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagExample extends JPanel {

   public GridBagExample() {
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

      add(new JButton("Refresh"), createGbc(0, 0));
      add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(12, 20)), createGbc(1, 0, 5, 1));


      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         String text = "Button: " + (10 - i); 
         JButton button = new JButton(text);
         add(button, createGbc(i, 1));
      }
   }

   private GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y) {
      return createGbc(x, y, 1, 1);
   }

   private GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.gridwidth = w;
      gbc.gridheight = h;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
      return gbc;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      GridBagExample mainPanel = new GridBagExample();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagExample");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I did as you said (check my edit on the code) and I added pack() as well which gave me this :

http://i.imgur.com/x2EyaHJ.png

It's still not right :s

Comment: @HishamMohammed: see my code above. If still stuck, show your code, but do as I did -- create a small self-contained compilable and runnable program that shows the problem (or solution) directly for us. This is a good tool to use on most questions here and on debugging in general -- isolate the problem.

Comment: *"grid.gridwidth should likely be 5"* or `GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER` if you're lazy ;)

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the problem by changing the grid.gridwidth to 5, and by then changing grid.gridwidth back to 1 on the following row.